# Show that $\{\sup B_n < \infty\}$ is in the tail $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory

I'm trying to prove that $\{\sup B_n < \infty\}$ is in the tail $\sigma$-algebra, where $B_n $ is a Brownian motion and the tail $\sigma $-algebra is the one given by the natural filtration.

It is not hard to show that $$\{\sup B_n < \infty\}= \bigcup_u^\infty \bigcap_m^\infty \{\max_{i \le m }  B_i \le u\}.$$

Now I wonder how to argue from this? We need to show that for any $m_0 $: $\bigcup_u^\infty \bigcap_m^\infty \{\max_{i \le m }  B_i \le u\} \in \sigma (\mathcal F_{m_0},F_{m_0+1},F_{m_0+2}...)$, and it is sufficient that $\bigcap_m^\infty \{\max_{i \le m }  B_i \le u\} \in \sigma (\mathcal F_{m_0},F_{m_0+1},F_{m_0+2}...)$ for this to hold.

Every $\{\max_{i \le m }  B_i \le u\}$ is in $ \sigma(\mathcal F_m ) $ and thus in $\sigma (\mathcal F_{m},F_{m+1},F_{m+2}...)$, but how would I motivate that for every $k$: $\bigcap_m^\infty \{\max_{i \le m }  B_i \le u\} $ is in $\sigma (\mathcal F_{k},F_{k+1},F_{k+2}...)$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach doesn't work because you are using every $B_k$. The event $\{\sup_{n\geq 1} B_n <\infty \}$ is same as $\{\sup_{n \geq k} B_n <\infty \}$ for any positive integer $k$. Hence it belongs to $\sigma (\{B_k,B_{k+1},...\})$.